# Alpine Linux Docker Image - Installing libnsl

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am using Alpine Linux 3.18
My base image is [gradle:7.6.1-jdk17-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/gradle/7.6.1-jdk17-alpine/images/sha256-9205fbf97895ffb3c15fa6cb1345c9204afbaa69d9831c71e8be7bb752e73364?context=repo&tab=vulnerabilities)

```
 RUN export ALPINE_VERSION=$(cat /etc/alpine-release | cut -d "." -f 1-2) && ` rm /etc/apk/repositories && \ 
 echo "@main local_nexus/repository/alpine-proxy/v$ALPINE_VERSION/main" > /etc/apk/repositories && \ 
 echo "@community local_nexus/repository/alpine-proxy/v$ALPINE_VERSION/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
    
  # Install build tools
  RUN apk add --no-cache \
      git@main \
      docker-cli@community \
      curl@main \
      libaio@main \
      libc6-compat@main \
      libnsl@community && \
      rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

I am getting following error.

```
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  libtirpc-conf-1.3.3-r2:
    masked in: @main
    satisfies: libtirpc-1.3.3-r2[libtirpc-conf]
  krb5-conf-1.0-r2:
    masked in: @main
    satisfies: krb5-libs-1.20.1-r1[krb5-conf]
  libcom_err-1.47.0-r2:
    masked in: @main
    satisfies: krb5-libs-1.20.1-r1[so:libcom_err.so.2]
  keyutils-libs-1.6.3-r3:
    masked in: @main
    satisfies: krb5-libs-1.20.1-r1[so:libkeyutils.so.1]
  libverto-0.3.2-r2:
    masked in: @main
    satisfies: krb5-libs-1.20.1-r1[so:libverto.so.1]
  krb5-libs-1.20.1-r1:
    masked in: @main
    satisfies: libtirpc-1.3.3-r2[so:libgssapi_krb5.so.2]
  libtirpc-1.3.3-r2:
    masked in: @main
    satisfies: libnsl-2.0.0-r0[so:libtirpc.so.3]
```

To install packages, I am using a corporate Nexus proxy URL which points to Alpine package repository. Other packages get installed without any complain which means there is no issue with the connectivity / certificates.

Any suggestions please

**libnsl** depends on 3 packages
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.18/community/x86/libnsl
One of them is **libtripc**, which depends on **libtirpc-conf**
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.18/main/x86/libtirpc-conf

Comment: Using the same base image, if I simply run `apk add libnsl` it completes without errors ([log](https://gist.github.com/larsks/b8295afa514d4a6ffffee4857e961346)). If I run the commands you show in your question, `apk` fails with several errors along the lines of `The repository tag for world dependency 'git@main' does not exist`. `apk add git docker-cli curl libaio libc6-compat libnsl` works as well.

Comment: @larsks I have it in the same way,
` libaio@main \`
` libc6-compat@main \`
` libnsl@community && \`

Comment: It doesn't look like you're running the same command that I am running.

Comment: That is because I have defined main and community repos through Nexus

`RUN export ALPINE_VERSION=$(cat /etc/alpine-release | cut -d "." -f  1-2) && \`
        rm /etc/apk/repositories && \
        echo "@main https://local_nexus/repository/alpine-proxy/v$ALPINE_VERSION/main" > /etc/apk/repositories && \
        echo "@community https://local_nexus/repository/alpine-proxy/v$ALPINE_VERSION/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dockefile`

```
FROM gradle:7.6.1-jdk17-alpine

RUN export ALPINE_VERSION=$(cat /etc/alpine-release | cut -d "." -f 1-2) && \
    rm /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo "https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v$ALPINE_VERSION/main" > /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo "https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v$ALPINE_VERSION/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        git \
        docker-cli \
        curl \
        libaio \
        libc6-compat \
        libnsl && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

You don't need to specify the `main` and `community` repositories when installing the packages.

I believe that the issue with your approach arises from the `@main` and `@community` at the beginning of the lines you are inserting into `/etc/apk/repositories`. Remove those and the packages should install.

Since I don't have access to your proxy repositories, that's impossible to test.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, removing main & community from repos fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Work around if you want to keep the `@main` and `@community`, is to install the dependant packages manually.

```
  libaio@main \
  libc6-compat@main \
  libintl@main \
  libtirpc@main \
  musl@main \
  libnsl@community \
```

`libnsl` is in `community` but its dependant packages are in `main`, when you provide the package name as `libnsl@community` it cannot find the dependant packages in `main` This is what I suspect, I could be wrong.